# ssh inline proxy jump using keys is not working

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I need to establish a connection to a remote server via proxy jump. I'm trying to use the -J flag to do that. I understand that the syntax looks like this:

```
ssh -J A B
```

But I need to use key files for both connections. So I've tried this:

```
ssh -J -i /path/proxy.pem user@proxy_host -i /path/target.pem user@target_host
```

Obviously it's not working, I'm getting

```
option requires an argument -- i
usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
           [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port] [-Q query_option] [-R address]
           [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
           [user@]hostname [command]
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

What is the correct inline syntax in this case, without editing ssh settings? In this case there is no difference which server the keys are stored on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I understand that the syntax looks like this:
>
> ```
> ssh -J A B
> ```

Yes, but that's not the whole story. `-J` is not a standalone flag – it doesn't simply let you specify two independent sets of connection options in the same command line, as you're trying to do.

Instead, the `-J` flag takes the intermediate host's name *as a parameter*, so just like `-i <keyfile>` always go together, `-J <proxy>` must also remain together.

And even if you use this option, the overall 'ssh' syntax doesn't change – there's still no grouping of which options belong to host A and which belong to host B. If you have two '-i' options like that, SSH will just try *both* keys when making each of the two connections.

The latter part shouldn't be a problem, however, as each server will just indicate that it doesn't accept the key and SSH will try another. So the following should work:

```
ssh -J user@proxy_host -i /path/proxy.pem -i /path/target.pem user@target_host
    └────────────────┘ └────────────────┘ └─────────────────┘
```

But if one of the hosts doesn't like the fact that multiple keys are being tried, you will need to translate the -J into long-form ProxyCommand:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -i /path/proxy.pem -W %h:%p user@proxy_host" -i /path/target.pem user@target_host
```

Comment: Your first solution didn't work, because the first key is just ignored, but the second solution works just fine, so thanks.

Comment: The documentation says that multiple `-i` options are allowed and get combined into a list – so it should work as long as each server only accepts the correct key, unless the docs are wrong. (But I can see situations where it wouldn't work, e.g. if proxy_host was configured by an asshole and is _accepting_ the "target.pem" key just to immediately kick you off afterwards.)

Comment: With the first example I'm getting `Permission denied (publickey).` which is what normally happens when key is not included or key is wrong. The `proxy_host` configuration is out of the box default Ubuntu 18.04 install, I control the server. In any case, so long as the second way is working I'm fine. Thanks.

Comment: Another option is to set up your ssh `config` file with `IdentityFile` entries for the two hosts (see the second example [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/force-ssh-client-to-use-given-private-key-identity-file/), and the right ones will be used automatically. You could even add `ProxyJump proxy_host` to the section for `target_host` (and a `User` entry in the `proxy_host` section), and it'll automate the jump step entirely.

Comment: Yes, but OP did specifically ask "without editing ssh settings".